# What exactly is a "generic hierarchical" file system and why does it behave differently than NTFS?

Tags: windows, android

I'm trying to understand what explains the differences seen for a `Generic hierarchical` filesystem to a regular NTFS mount as experienced in the Explorer application.

If I plug in a Motorola XT1080 Android 5.1 phone to my Windows 7 PC it launches the internal storage window in Explorer. If I click on the properties for that folder I find the following display, the key curiosity being this labeling of a `Generic hierarchical` file system.

[image: Folder properties for Internal Storage folder on Android]

The navigation of this file system is very close to navigating folders of the NTFS file system on the hardrive of that PC but with a few curious differences I'll enumerate below.

### Confusion about Empty Folders on Device

For instance, if I check the properties of any non-empty folder on the phone it shows a storage size of 0 and with no contents. If I manually open that folder I find files and subdirectories. Why the difference in behavior there?

[image: sub folder in Internal Storage with folder properties displayed]

### Null Data in Created Column for Details View

Another difference can be seen probing the properties of files under the Internal Storage. If I look at a folder of images for example in the Camera folder they list no metadata for the Created column.

[image: File details view showing no data in the Created column]

### Poor/Rich File Property Details

If I open the properties for one image on the phone I see this view...

[image: file properties of file on phone]

and If I move that file to a folder on my PC, in this case C:\Temp, I see the following...

[image: file properties of the file on the PC computer]

Why is more rich data presented from the PC but not the phone?

### Accessible from Command Line

There's other differences too in that I can open a command prompt to C:\Temp but not to what shows up under `Computer` as `Portable Devices XT1058 Portable Media Player`
[image: cell phone as appears under Computer folder]

Which if I drill into shows the following path in the address bar `Computer\XT1058\Internal storage`

```
c:\temp>cd Computer\XT1058\Internal storage
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

What can explain why there's so much differences in behavior with this superficially similar looking file system encountered through Explorer?

---

### Relation to MTP

I'm wondering if a clue can be found from when I first plug in the phone to the PC. I immediately see this popup telling me that the phone is `Connected as a media device` which matches the terminology from Explorer labeling the device as a portable media device.

[image: Connected as a media device screen shot]

If I touch that notification popup on the phone I see the `other USB options` they mention...

[image: USB computer connection settings]

I see that the phone is configured as

```
Connect as
Media Device (MTP)
Lets you transfer media files on Windows.
```

What's the relationship of MTP to Generic hierarchical file systems?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: Aha, so Generic hiercharchical is probably a side effect attribute of the device being with connected through this MTP protocol. That wiki article does make some valid points, in that two devices behaving independent of each other are seeing the same storage and some means of mediation must be imposed. This is unlike a USB thumbdrive which has no smarts to manipulate itself independent of the PC.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: [The comment form is not the answer form.](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2640/should-answers-be-posted-as-comments-if-we-are-not-sure-of-the-answer#comment5903_2643)